# HTTP error wordpress upon uploading swf files

Tags: wordpress, flash, http

I'm facing HTTP error while uploading swf file more than 3 mb in wordpress 3.9.3. I have changed upload_max_size to 6400M and upload post_size to 100M but still problem exists. My site is hosted on godaddy VPS. I have enough memory to upload files. I've tried every possibility. Using cpanel or ftp I can upload files but from admin panel this error occurs. Is there anyone who can tell me the root cause of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress version 3.6.1 and higher (like in your case 3.9.3) doesn't allow uploading SWF files anymore.

Source http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_3.6.1:

*Additional security hardening:
Updated security restrictions around file uploads to mitigate the potential for cross-site scripting.
The extensions .swf and .exe are no longer allowed by default, and .htm and .html are only allowed if the user has the ability to use unfiltered HTML.*

So you have 3 options:

1. don't upload SWF file at all
2. convert SWF file to MP4 (for example)
3. or create a custom WordPress template as described here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/116767/add-swf-file-to-wordpress-through-custom-template